# Component Event is not triggering

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning, lightning-apps, lightning-experience

I am trying to list the contact after the double clicking the input text box in lightning component`

Component:

```
<aura:component implements="force:appHostable" controller="sc">
  <aura:registerEvent name="cmp" type="c:searchevt"/>
   <ui:inputText aura:id="name" dblclick="{!c.searchKeyChange}"/>
    <aura:handler name="cmp" event="c:searchevt" action="{!c.keych}"/>
    <aura:attribute name="contacts" type="Contact[]"/>
     <aura:iteration items="{!v.contacts}" var="contact">
                <p>{!contact.Name}</p>
                <p>{!contact.Phone}</p>
      </aura:iteration>
     </aura:component>
```

**Controller Js**

```
({
searchKeyChange: function(component, event, helper) {
    var searchstring =component.find("name").get("v.value");
    console.log(searchstring);
    var appEvent = component.getEvent("cmp");
    appEvent.setParam({"searchKe": searchstring});
    appEvent.fire();
    console.log(searchKe);
},
keych: function(component, event, helper) {
var searchkey = event.getParam("searchKe");
console.log(searchKe);
console.log(searchkey);
var action = component.get("c.getfindByName");
action.setParams({
  "searchKey": searchkey
});
 action.setCallback(this, function(a) {
    alert("success");
    component.set("v.contacts",a.getReturnValue());
 });
   $A.enqueueAction(action);
  }
})
```

**event:**

```
<-----c:searchevt--->
<aura:event type="COMPONENT" access="global">
  <aura:attribute name="searchKe" type="String"/>
</aura:event>
```

**Apex class**

```
@AuraEnabled
public static List<Contact> getfindByName(String searchKey) {
    String namex = '%' + searchKey + '%';
    return [SELECT id, name, phone FROM Contact WHERE name LIKE :namex];
}
```

> I am getting error as searchKe is not defined

Comment: Add <aura:attribute name="searchKe" type="String"/> in component.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are couple of things I have noticed here

1.Use setParams() when you are setting parameters for firing component event

2.dbclick has a bug that for first time it does not read the correct value .You can use blur event which worked perfectly for me .Also get rid of wrong console logs from the code and lightning is very sensitive to the variable names .I corrceted few variable names .

The corrected code is as below

```
<aura:component implements="force:appHostable,flexipage:availableForAllPageTypes,flexipage:availableForRecordHome,force:hasRecordId" access="global" controller="sc">
 <aura:registerEvent name="cmp" type="c:searchevt"/>
 <ui:inputText aura:id="name" blur="{!c.searchKeyChange}"/>
  <aura:handler name="cmp" event="c:searchevt" action="{!c.keych}"/>
  <aura:attribute name="contacts" type="Contact[]"/>
   <aura:iteration items="{!v.contacts}" var="contact">
            <p>{!contact.Name}</p>
            <p>{!contact.Phone}</p>
   </aura:iteration>
</aura:component>
```

The JS code

```
({
searchKeyChange: function(component, event, helper) {
    var searchstring = component.find("name").get("v.value");
    console.log(searchstring);
    var appEvent = component.getEvent("cmp");
    appEvent.setParams({"searchKe": searchstring});//NOTICE HOW I USED setParams instead of setParam .
    appEvent.fire();
},
keych: function(component, event, helper) {
    console.log(event.getName());
    var searchkey = event.getParam("searchKe");//Notice the string names are so sensitive .
    console.log(searchkey);
    var action = component.get("c.getfindByName");
    action.setParams({
      "searchKey": searchkey
    });
     action.setCallback(this, function(a) {
        alert("success");
        component.set("v.contacts",a.getReturnValue());
     });
       $A.enqueueAction(action);
    }
})
```

Comment: Hey Mohith,Thanks for pointing out correctly.Similarly for the keyup also it is coming as undefined for the first time.I have tested it out.

Comment: I would simply use inputtext of HTML Incase these bugs exist .But blur should get you what you need